# How detect jface dialog location?

Tags: dialog, mouse, drag, rcp

I hope to detect the mouse drag the TitleAreaDialog. So I try to add "DragDetectListener" and "MouseListener" to the dialog's shell. I found that when I drag this dialog, it doesn't call this listener. I also try to add "SWT.DragDetect" to shell.getDisplay() but this did not help.

Does anyone add this listener before?

```java
shell.addDragDetectListener(new DragDetectListener() {

  @Override
  public void dragDetected(DragDetectEvent e) {
    System.out.println("dragDetected-------------");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving a dialog doesn't trigger drag and drop events.

You can use a `ControlListener` to be told about move and resize events:

```java
newShell.addControlListener(new ControlListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void controlResized(final ControlEvent e)
    {
      // Resized
    }


    @Override
    public void controlMoved(final ControlEvent e)
    {
      // Moved
    }
  });
```

Note that you only get the `controlMoved` call once at the end of moving the dialog.